# QuadBounds Order for PdfAnnotation markup using itext or pdfbox

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

```
  0  1                      2  3
 *  (x1,y1) ***************  (x2,y2)
 *          *             *
 *          *             *             
 *   4  5   *             *    6 7       
 *  (x3,y3) ***************  (x4,y4)
```

is this correct order for float array for PdfAnnotation or PDFAnnotation? i tried creating a pdf annotation but the annotations are concave not convex like the those generally created by using adobe reader or acrobat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found using iText was the following:

```
*     4  5                         6  7
*   (x3, y3)  *****************  (x4, y4)
*             *               *
*             *               *
*             *               *
*     0  1    *               *    2  3
*   (x1, y1)  *****************  (x2, y2)
```

Using this order made my highlights output with the same convex effect as the highlight annotation tool in Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: yes.i had this issue with annotation when i switched from pdfbox to iText.The order was different in pdfbox and itext and that in the pdf iso documents.There were concave borders because the quadrilateral was twisted.

Answer (score 1):

The Pdf specification states on the quadrilateral coordinates:

> The coordinates for each quadrilateral are given in the order
>
> x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4
>
> specifying the four vertices of the quadrilateral in **counterclockwise** order. For orientation purposes, such as when applying an underline border style, the **bottom** of a quadrilateral is the line formed by **(x1, y1) and (x2, y2)**.
>
> *(multiple subsections of section 12.5.6 in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus:

```
*   6  7                      4  5       
*  (x4,y4) ***************  (x3,y3)
*          *             *
*          *             *             
*   0  1   *             *    2  3
*  (x1,y1) ***************  (x2,y2)
```

Comment: it's the same for pdf libraries? esp pdfbox and itext?

Comment: That is how all libraries have to write the coordinates into the annotation. What they expect as parameters from you might differ theoretically. That being said, iText in `PdfAnnotation.createMarkup` and PDFBox in `PDAnnotationLink` and `PDAnnotationTextMarkup` use the values as they come.

Comment: nope that did not work.the annotation was deformed.i used itext.

Comment: Then please supply a short program illustrating the issue. Maybe your issue has a different cause altogether.

Comment: thanks i finally figured out what is wrong.the order was correct from the start

Comment: Well, the order you presented in your question was ***not** correct* according to the PDF specification. PDF viewers may still display what you want, but they, especially Adobe Reader, are quite forgiving in that respect.

Comment: @Alvin I'm having the same issue as you using iText. What did you figure out to make it work? The order you presented in your question gives me concave highlights

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with iText 2.1.7 and it was driving me crazy. The order jrubins described did not work for me, it produced concave annotations. Eventually i found the right order, which is lr > ll > ur > ul .

```
    /* 
     * PDF Specification Order - results in broken annotation
     * 
     *  7,8             5, 6
     *  (x,y)___________(x,y)
     *      |           |
     *      |           |
     *      |___________|
     *  (x,y)           (x,y)
     *  1, 2            3, 4 
     */

    /* 
     * Concave order - results in working, but concave annotation; don't know why
     * 
     *  5, 6            7, 8
     *  (x,y)___________(x,y)
     *      |           |
     *      |           |
     *      |___________|
     *  (x,y)           (x,y)
     *  1, 2            3, 4 
     */

    /* 
     * Convex order - this is the one working like expected:
     * 
     *  7,8             5, 6
     *  (x,y)___________(x,y)
     *      |           |
     *      |           |
     *      |___________|
     *  (x,y)           (x,y)
     *  3, 4            1, 2 
     */

    float[] quad = { rect.getRight(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getLeft(),rect.getBottom(), rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(),
            rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop() };
```